# MySQL Pass max() column as interval days

Tags: mysql, sql, having

I have problem with passing `MAX(t.to_days) as max_days` to `DATE_ADD(t.date, INTERVAL max_days DAY)`.

Query:

```
select t.*, MAX(t.to_days) as max_days
  from transactions t 
  where CURRENT_DATE > DATE_ADD(t.date, INTERVAL max_days  DAY)
```

returning error: Unknown column 'max_days' in 'where clause'.

I also tried:

```
select t.*, @num:=CAST(MAX(t.to_days) AS UNSIGNED) 
  from transactions t 
  where CURRENT_DATE > DATE_ADD(t.date, INTERVAL @num  DAY)
```

but `DATE_ADD` returning `null`.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample input table with some rows (maybe 5-10 rows) and the desired output result set you want to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any sample data and expect result, but I guess you can try to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`, because `MAX` is 
*Aggregate function*, and judgment can't use alias name.

```
select t.*, MAX(to_days) as max_days 
from transactions t 
HAVING CURRENT_DATE > DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL MAX(to_days) DAY)
```

Here is my mock sample [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b22d/1)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly writing this query as:

```
select t.*, tt.max_days
from transactions t cross join
     (select max(t.to_days) as max_days from transactions t) tt
where t.date < date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval tt.max_days day);
```

Why?  This version should be able to take advantage of an index on `transactions(to_day)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use a sub query to get the `MAX()` value and use it in your `DATE_ADD()` expression.

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    transactions t
WHERE
    CURRENT_DATE > DATE_ADD(t.date, INTERVAL (
        SELECT
            MAX(to_days)
        FROM
            transactions) DAY)
```